# How to update a specific line in a file in python?

Tags: python, file, python-3.6, fileupdate

I am trying to create a program which can update a file.
I created a test program as I cannot figure out how to update a part of the file.

I want to make it so that if a name matches that of one in the file, it will delete the one name and its data and place the name and new data at the end.

Here is my code where I am simply trying to remove the name from the list:

```
lines = open("input.txt", "rt")
output = open("output.txt", "wt")
for line in lines:
    if not "Ben":
        output.write(line+"\n")
lines.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: The condition `not "Ben"` will always evaluate to `False`. It takes the string "Ben" and converts it to a `bool`, resulting in `True`, since the string is non-empty; `not` results in the negation of `True`, yielding `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you just need to fix your condition:

```
lines = open("input.txt", "rt")
output = open("output.txt", "wt")
for line in lines:
    if "Ben" not in line:
        output.write(line+"\n")
lines.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: This is usually written as `"Ben" not in line` in Python.  It's completely equivalent, but is more similar to English when read.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = open("input.txt", "rt")
output = open("output.txt", "wt")
for line in lines:
    if not "Ben" in line:
        output.write(line+"\n")
    else:
        output.write(line.replace("Ben","replace/delete Ben")+"\n")
lines.close()
output.close()
```

Comment: he wanted to add the new line at the end of the file, therefore it shouldn't be included here.